# Tune K for kmeans clustering using Tidymodels, Workflowsets and Recipes

Tags: r, tidymodels, tidyclust

I wish to select the optimal value of K for K means clustering using Tidymodels. I'm exploring using workflowsets to provide a number of preprocessing recipes and I wish to compare their performance when selecting a value for K.

I'm trying to follow along to [this tutorial](https://tidyclust.tidymodels.org/articles/tuning_and_metrics.html) in combination with [this one](https://workflowsets.tidymodels.org/articles/tuning-and-comparing-models.html) which discusses using workflowsets for comparing models.

I'm using the mtcars data and I've been stuck on the hyper-parameter tuning section where I'm trying to collect the tuning results. See my code below.

I'm stuck at the section where I have a workflowset and am passing it to tune_cluster. I receive the following error:

`Error in` tune_cluster()`: The first argument to [tune_cluster()] should be either a model or workflow.`

```
# INSTALL PACKAGES
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, tidymodels, tidyclust, janitor, ClusterR, knitr, moments, visdat, skimr, DescTools)

mtcars <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(
    `am` = factor(`am`, labels = c(`0` = "auto", `1` = "man")),
    `vs` = factor(`vs`, labels = c(`0` = "V-shaped", `1` = "straight")),
    `cyl` = factor(`cyl`),
    `gear` = factor(`gear`),
    `carb` = factor(`carb`)
  )

# SET UP 10 FOLD CROSS VALIDATION
mtcars_cv <- vfold_cv(mtcars, v = 10)

# SET SEED FOR REPRODUCABILITY
set.seed(123)


# EDA ---------------------------------------------------------------------

#skimr::skim(mtcars)

#DescTools::Desc(mtcars)


# MODEL SPEC --------------------------------------------------------------

kmeans_spec <- k_means(num_clusters = tune())


# PREPROCESSING RECIPES ---------------------------------------------------

rec1 <- recipe(~., data = mtcars) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors()) %>%
  step_zv(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors())

rec2 <- recipe(~., data = mtcars) %>%
  step_novel(all_nominal()) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal()) %>%
  step_zv(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_normalize(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_pca(all_predictors(), num_comp = 2)

rec3 <- recipe(~., data = mtcars) %>%
  step_log(all_numeric_predictors()) %>%
  step_center(all_numeric_predictors()) %>%
  step_scale(all_numeric_predictors())


clust_num_grid <- grid_regular(num_clusters(),
  levels = 10
)

# WORKFLOW ----------------------------------------------------------------

wf_set <- workflow_set(
  preproc = list(rec1, rec2, rec3),
  models = list(kmeans_spec)
)


# TUNE HYPER-PARAMETERS ---------------------------------------------------

tune_results <- wf_set %>%
  workflow_map(
    resamples = mtcars_cv,
    grid = clust_num_grid
  ) %>%
  tune_cluster(
    resamples = mtcars_cv,
    grid = clust_num_grid,
    metrics = cluster_metric_set(sse_within_total, sse_total, sse_ratio),
    control = tune::control_grid(save_pred = TRUE, extract = identity)
  )

best_wf <- tune_results %>%
  select_best("sse_ratio")
```

Any help to overcome this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the post! Emil (tidyclust maintainer) and I (workflowsets maintainer) just chatted about this.

The workflowsets idiom for tuning these models would look like:

```r
tune_results <-
   wf_set %>% 
   workflow_map(
      "tune_cluster",
      resamples = mtcars_cv,
      grid = clust_num_grid,
      metrics = cluster_metric_set(sse_within_total, sse_total, sse_ratio),
      control = tune::control_grid(save_pred = TRUE, extract = identity)
   )
```

...but workflowsets currently prevents you from passing `"tune_cluster"` as your tuning function. I've [filed an issue](https://github.com/tidymodels/workflowsets/issues/115) on the package repository to remind myself to add support for this.

In the meantime, you could approximate this process with something like:

```r
tune_cluster_wf <- function(id) {
   tune_cluster(
      extract_workflow(wf_set, id),
      resamples = mtcars_cv,
      grid = clust_num_grid,
      metrics = cluster_metric_set(sse_within_total, sse_total, sse_ratio),
      control = tune::control_grid(save_pred = TRUE, extract = identity)
   )
}

wf_set$result <- lapply(wf_set$wflow_id, tune_cluster_wf)
```

The third element throws an error from the recipe, but I'll let you troubleshoot from there. :)

Comment: thanks for looking into this, this worked a treat! Thanks so much

Comment: Is this the best approach to plot the results: tune_results <- wf_set %>% 
  collect_metrics() %>%
  filter(.metric == "sse_ratio")

tune_results %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(stringr::str_sub(.config,-2,-1)), y = mean,color = wflow_id)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  theme_minimal() +
  ggtitle("Plot of WSS/TSS ratio by Cluster Number") +
  ylab("mean WSS/TSS ratio, over 10 folds") +
  xlab("Number of clusters") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10)